# Play Framework 2 & AngularJS - Partial Handling

Tags: angularjs, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am starting to develop a business spa application (mobile/desktop web app) with Play Framework 2 and AngularJS. Right now I am tending to go with following solution:

- Play behaves as a RESTful application
- Play also pre-processes partials
- AngularJS handles the rest

My arguments for pre-processing partials are:

- Play can remove parts of a partial for a more compact mobile view
- Different user roles see more/less content of the partial
- Correct language will be loaded into the partial

Are there any disadvantages with this approach? Do you think this would be the best solution for the project's requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server-side templating is usually what you want to get rid of when building an SPA. In general this should work, but there are a couple of disadvantages:

- You are mixing two template languages, Play and AngularJS, so you must be careful not create an unmaintainable mess
- Your display logic will also be distributed or duplicated between Angular and Play; in a pure RESTful approach Play would mostly be concerned about access control and JSON (input, output, validation)
- You must create a route for every partial instead of just using the assets route
- Server side templating slows down compilation speed
- Returning different content depending on roles and desktop/mobile *might* mess with Angular's $template cache

> Different user roles see more/less content of the partial

This should be handled by Angular IMHO, Play would just make sure to only serve the appropriate JSON to the right users.

> Correct language will be loaded into the partial

How would you reuse Play's `Lang` in Angular? Build an inline variable? Again, just load it via JSON when the app bootstraps.

Comment: I accepted your answer cause your points are valid and make sense. However, if I do the user role templating with angular I'll end up implementing authorization in angular AND play. Is this the usual approach?

Comment: Yes, your server will always have to handle authorization. The client will have to select what to display for a given user role. The client does not filter the data, that's the server's responsibility.